# How to proceed in Isabelle when the goal has implications and existentials?

Tags: isabelle, proof, theorem-proving, formal-verification, isar

I'm trying to write a proof in the Isabelle "structured style" and I'm not sure how to specify the value of existential variables. Specifically, I'm trying to expand the `sorry`s in this proof:

```
lemma division_theorem: "lt Zero n ⟹ ∃ q r. lt r n ∧ m = add (mul q n) r"
proof (induct m)
  case Zero
  then show ?case
    by (metis add_zero_right mul.simps(1)) 
next
  case (Suc m)
  then show ?case
  proof (cases "Suc r = n")
    case True
    then show ?thesis sorry
  next
    case False
    then show ?thesis sorry
  qed
qed
```

`Zero`, `add`, and `mul` are defined on a nat-like class that I made just for the purposes of writing simple number theory proofs, hopefully that is intuitive. I have done this in the "apply" style, so I'm familiar with how the proof is supposed to go, I'm just not understanding how to turn it into "structured" style.

So the goals generated by these cases are:

```
 1. (lt Zero n ⟹ ∃q r. lt r n ∧ m = add (mul q n) r) ⟹
    lt Zero n ⟹ cnat.Suc r = n ⟹ ∃q r. lt r n ∧ cnat.Suc m = add (mul q n) r
 2. (lt Zero n ⟹ ∃q r. lt r n ∧ m = add (mul q n) r) ⟹
    lt Zero n ⟹ cnat.Suc r ≠ n ⟹ ∃q r. lt r n ∧ cnat.Suc m = add (mul q n) r
```

At a high level, for that first goal, I want to grab the `q` and `r` from the first existential, specify `q' = Suc q` and `r' = Zero` for the second existential, and let sledgehammer bash out precisely what mix of arithmetic lemmas to use to prove that it works. And then do that same for `q' = q` and `r' = Suc r` for the second case.

How can I do this? I have tried various mixes of `obtain`, `rule exI`, but I feel like I'm not understanding some basic mechanism here. Using the apply style this works when I apply `subgoal_tac` but it seems like that is unlikely to be the ideal method of solution here.

Comment: For reference the rest of the code, including definitions of Zero, add_zero_right, etc, is here: https://github.com/lacker/kata/blob/master/isabelle/Division.thy .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the two goals generated by the command `cases "Suc r = n"`, the occurrences of variable `r` in both the expressions `cnat.Suc r = n` and `cnat.Suc r ≠ n` are actually *free* and thus not related to the existentially quantified formula whatsoever. In order to "grab" the `q` and `r` from the induction hypothesis you need to use the `obtain` command. As a side remark, I suggest to use the `induction` method instead of the `induct` method so you can refer to the induction hypothesis as `Suc.IH` instead of `Suc.hyps`. Once you "grab" `q` and `r` from the induction hypothesis, you just need to prove that

1. `lt r' n`, and that
2. `Suc m = add (mul q' n) r'`

with `q'` and `r'` as defined for each of your two cases. Here is a (slightly incomplete) proof of your division theorem:

```
lemma division_theorem: "lt Zero n ⟹ ∃ q r. lt r n ∧ m = add (mul q n) r"
proof (induction m)
  case Zero
  then show ?case
    by (metis add_zero_right mul.simps(1)) 
next
  case (Suc m)
  (* "Grab" q and r from IH *)
  from ‹lt Zero n› and Suc.IH obtain q and r where "lt r n ∧ m = add (mul q n) r"
    by blast
  show ?case
  proof (cases "Suc r = n")
    case True
    (* In this case, we use q' = Suc q and r' = Zero as witnesses  *)
    from ‹Suc r = n› and ‹lt r n ∧ m = add (mul q n) r› have "Suc m = add (mul (Suc q) n) Zero"
      using add_comm by auto
    with ‹lt Zero n› show ?thesis
      by blast
  next
    case False
    (* In this case, we use q' = q and r' = Suc r as witnesses  *)
    from ‹lt r n ∧ m = add (mul q n) r› have "Suc m = add (mul q n) (Suc r)"
      by simp
    moreover have "lt (Suc r) n"
      sorry (* left as exercise :) *)
    ultimately show ?thesis
      by blast
  qed
qed
```

Comment: Aha, thank you! The `r` was highlighted in the output window, which I should have realized hinted at some problem.